# Is it possible to add comments to COM objects inside C# code?

Tags: c#, .net, com

I was wondering if I can manually add comments to a COM class or enum that I'm using in my project.

Most of our programmers can use then without any trouble, but since we got some inexperienced programers in here, I was wondering if I could improve documentation adding some comments to the COM objects, interfaces and enums we use in our company.

Something like:

```
///<summary>This is a enum that doesn't do anything</summary>
enum ComApi.FooBar
{
  ///<summary>Does Foo</summary>
  Foo,
  ///<summary>Does Bar</summary>
  Bar,
  ///<summary>Does Foo and Bar, and divid by zero!</summary>
  Baz
}
```

If the above way is not possible, then is it possible to add the comments directly inside the COM dll?

By the way, I'm developing on VS 2008, with c#. I'm trying to improve our programmers experience by adding some comments to the COM objects, so that Visual Studio shows then in it's documentation interface.

Comment: Please don't be so lazy. What happens when you try the above code?

Comment: Did you try? Add some comments and build. If build succeed (It will succeed) it means yes it is possible :) You can find your own answer.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answers, but I think we are losing the point here.

In this post, I was just trying to figure out some ways to Add comments for my COM objects.

By the way, both Mr. Passant and Qwertie gave me great answers. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio, when you press F12 (Go To Definition) on a class that is defined in a DLL, Visual Studio shows a C# representation of the class, along with any documentation it finds about that class. Normally (always?) such documentation is stored in an XML file alongside the DLL. For example, a DLL called Foo.dll would have a Foo.xml file that contains documentation. Here is an example showing what the XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>Interop.MyComLib</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="T:MyComLib.IMyInterface">
            <summary>
            An interface for transforming actionable items into itemed actions.
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="M:MyComLib.IMyInterface.Dance(System.Boolean)">
            <summary>
            Causes any pending phat moves to be flushed to corporeal
            form in a visually pleasing manner.
            </summary>
            <param name="b">Must be true, or there will be a FalseException.</param>
            <returns>A <see cref="T:System.Boolean"/> containing the opposite of the 'b' argument.</returns>
        </member>
    </members>
</doc>
```

The XML file must be placed alongside the Primary Interop Assembly, which typically has a filename such as Interop.MyComLib.DLL if the COM library is MyCom.DLL. If the COM DLL doesn't have a specially-made Primary Interop Assembly then Visual Studio will generate an Interop assembly automatically, in which case there will be one copy in your obj\Debug folder (for the debug build) and another copy in the obj\Release folder (for the release build). If you make an XML file like this, and put it next to the Interop DLL (not the original COM DLL!) then VS should be able to find it.

There are also extra copies in the bin\* folders, but Visual Studio does not look for documentation in bin\*.

To help you create documentation, you could write a dummy project named after the Interop DLL, with public, do-nothing code:

```
namespace ComApiLib
{
    /// <summary>This is a enum that doesn't do anything</summary>
    public enum ComApi.FooBar
    {
      ///<summary>Does Foo</summary>
      Foo,
      ///<summary>Does Bar</summary>
      Bar,
    }
    /// <summary>This is a class</summary>
    public class Klass
    {
        ///<summary>Does Foo</summary>
        public void Foo() {}
        ///<summary>Does Bar</summary>
        public void Bar() {}
    }
}
```

In the project settings, in the Build tab, enable the "XML documentation file" checkbox. Then build your project, copy the XML file beside the Interop DLL (and give it the same name with XML extension), then see if Visual Studio recognizes the XML file (you might have to restart Visual Studio).

P.S. The "helpstring" attribute doesn't work for me. I don't see it displayed in Visual Studio anywhere. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: This is probably the solution that I'm going to adapt into my project. Thanks for the answer @Qwertie, and for the detailed codes you posted.

Answer (score 5):

COM type libraries *do* support comments through the [helpstring] attribute.  Many COM aware development environments display these comments in their editor.  However, this is not supported in .NET, a type library is generated from compiled code which has all comments removed.  And there is no attribute in .NET that lets Regasm.exe or Tlbexp.exe emit it into the .tlb.

If you want to pursue this then you'll have to write an .idl file.  You can get one out of the existing .tlb with OleView.exe, File + View Typelib command.  You can then edit the file to insert the [helpstring] attributes, midl.exe can translate it back into a type library.

The brutal part about it is that you have to *redo* this when the public interface of the C# code changes.  No joy without tooling.  And you *have* to automate it to ensure this type library cannot get out of step with the C# code.  That produces horrible runtime exceptions that are impossible to diagnose.  Like AccessViolationException.  Or worse, no exception at all, just wrong values when the stack gets imbalanced.  I'm not aware of an existing tool that does this.

Comment: Thanks for the knoledge sharing. I think I will avoid this solution, since you stated to me that it can lead to bad exceptions messages, and try the another one below, but it was a great answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Canella - these are two *opposite* ways of providing intellisense.  I assumed that you used C# to create a COM server, used by others.  @Qwertie shows the exact opposite, using a COM server written in another language in a C# program.  If you used C# to write a COM server that's used by C# programmers then you are doing it completely wrong.  It isn't that clear which is the scenario but you can't do both.

Comment: Hi @Hans. Actually, my problem fits the @Qwertie cenario you described. I'm sorry that I didn't make it clear in my original post. I will fix it later. But your answer was great either. Thank you for the enlightening.

Comment: Ahh, I just assumed that the question was about using a non-.NET COM server in C# ... but now that I look at the question again, I see it could be misinterpreted as a question about writing a COM server in C# and using it in some (non-dot-net) project.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're doing it won't work. Using a triple-slash to denote a comment causes VS to expect XML-formatted documentation. Read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/csharpcodedocumentation.aspx) for details. If you do it right, your programmers will then see the documentation through IntelliSense.

Comment: Hi there. I fixed the comments on my question and added the summary tag to then.

Just to state that I was aware of these tags on my font, but since I'm new to stack overflow, i forgot to add ` between the tags.

Anyway, thanks for your reminder.

Answer (score 1):

None of answers did actually answered on question.
And answer was very simple.
Documenting COM object ([[helpstring("...")]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/helpstring)) is possible in C# using [System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute?view=netframework-4.8) attribute. And '*Description*' attribute is available since .Net Framework version 1.1.

For example C# class definition:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// 4. 'Obj_Anforderung' - (Obj_request) <-- this works for documenting in XML for VS docs or documentation generation tools
  /// </summary>
#if COMLIB
  [ComVisible(true)]
  [Guid("E58D82B8-2104-4378-92AB-E63F2FAF1EE8")]
  [Description("4. 'Obj_Anforderung' - (Obj_request)")] // <-- this works for COM interops
#endif 
  [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
  public class Obj_Anforderung : GdtObj
  {
  }
```

When C# project is compiled with COM Interop true and Com Visible, we can see it's definition using OLE-COM viewer (any VS has this tool - look at Programs menu under visual studio sub groups):

```
[
  uuid(E58D82B8-2104-4378-92AB-E63F2FAF1EE8),
  version(1.0),
  helpstring("4. 'Obj_Anforderung' - (Obj_request)"),
  noncreatable,
  custom(0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9, "open.medical.gdt.definitions.Obj_Anforderung")
]
coclass Obj_Anforderung {
    [default] interface _Obj_Anforderung;
    interface _Object;
};
```

And as you can see [helpstring] is present and can be viewed with any standard IDE that supports COM [helpstring]. For example old VB6 sees it as

```
Class Obj_Anforderung
    Member of open_medical_gdt
    4. 'Obj_Anforderung' - (Obj_request)
```

Yes, this is general idea behind .Net COM Interops support (simplified version). If you have old, huge, and robust application supporting COM interop, and you do not want to port it to another language. You can write piece of code in .Net C#, and in old application just reference C# as COM Interop object library and use it normally as it is part of that programming environment.